# Getting a payload after calling 'update' method of CartEntryConnector

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I used 'updateEntry' method of ActiveCartService for updating the entry of the Cart. After then 'updateEntry$' effect from the CartEntryEffects class was triggered that returned new action.

```
updateEntry$: Observable = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(CartActions.CART_UPDATE_ENTRY),
    map((action: CartActions.CartUpdateEntry) => action.payload),
    concatMap(payload =>
      this.cartEntryConnector
        .update(payload.userId, payload.cartId, payload.entry, payload.qty)
        // should be my logic with payload
        .pipe(
          map(() => {
            return new CartActions.CartUpdateEntrySuccess({
              userId: payload.userId,
              cartId: payload.cartId,
            });
          }),
```

Which is the proper way to get this payload? 
Or can I override this effect or add my logic to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to do with the payload.

If you want to process it before the details get updated into Commerce, then that is generally handled by connectors & adapters.  See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/connecting-to-other-systems/

If you want to reference the updated entry & display it, then you can get hold of an Observable via the ActiveCartService. See for example the AddToCart component (https://sap.github.io/spartacus/components/AddToCartComponent.html#source) which declares `cartEntry$: Observable<OrderEntry>` and then in *ngOnInit()* does `this.cartEntry$ = this.activeCartService.getEntry(this.productCode)`